# How to trim out 'module.exports' in webpack loader and get plain string?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, webpack, loader

I'm writing the loader for webpack that preprocess arrow functions in html to classic functions. I'm going to use it with knockoutjs. 
For preprocessing I use this [package](https://github.com/danderson00/knockout-arrows)

For now I have

```
var rewrite = require('knockout-arrows');

module.exports = function (str) {
  if (this.cacheable) {
      this.cacheable();
  }

  var template = rewrite(str);

  return "module.exports = '"  + template + "'";
};
```

It works fine when I directly preprocess .html file. But when using other loader in the chain (eg `require("knockout-arrows!jade!./file.jade")`) it becomes broken, since `jade` loader also returns string with `"module.exports = '<h1>example</h1>'"`.

So my question is how to cut this 'module.exports' and get the plain string? Surely, i can use regex, but I think it's wrong.

Sorry for kind of noob question.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Jade loader doesn't return rendered HTML, but a compiled template function.

Comment: @robertklep yes, and this is the problem I'm trying to solve. It seems, I just don't understand the philosophy of loaders.
Jade returns exactly this javascript string `"module.exports = '<p>test</p>'`

Comment: Are your Jade files static (in other words: are they independent of any variables that need to be rendered)?

Comment: @robertklep yes, they are static

Comment: @robertklep sorry, missunderstood you. Jade returns string, not compiled template function. But this string contains (as i wrote before) `module.exports`, but i need a just plain string

Comment: But the _string_ will contain the compiled template function, and not the rendered HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121154/discussion-between-veikedo-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chat it turned out that you're using [`jade-static-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-static-loader), which exports a string containing a module export containing the HTML.

In other words, this is the *string* that the loader is getting:

```
"module.exports = '...HTML string...'"
```

To extract the HTML, you can use `eval()` (which in this case should be safe), and subsequently run the replacement code:

```
var rewrite = require('knockout-arrows');

module.exports = function (str) {
  if (this.cacheable) {
      this.cacheable();
  }
  var html     = eval(str);
  var template = rewrite(html);

  // Export the replaced HTML as another string:
  return "module.exports = "  + JSON.stringify(template);
};
```

Comment: Ehy dont they just return with a plain string?

Comment: @user1693057 "they"?

Comment: I mean, why do the developers of a loader return with 
`return "module.exports = " + JSON.stringify(input);`

instead of `return input;`
What's the point of it?

Comment: @user1693057 that's how loaders for Webpack are implemented, the result [_"...should be a String or a Buffer (...), representing the JavaScript source code of the module"_](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#writing-a-loader).

Comment: I was just confused, because I'm trying to write a loader, and it works if I give back only a plain string without any module export. That's why I haven't understood the point of writing it (module.export) instead of a plain string. It requires then parsing etc.

Comment: @user1693057 right, I understand :) To be honest, I always assumed that `module.exports = ...` was mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [val-loader](https://github.com/webpack/val-loader) in between the jade loader and yours? I had this same problem trying to use `haml` and `dust` loaders:

Changed from:

```
{ test: /\.js\.dust\.haml/, loader: 'dust-loader!haml-haml' }
```

to:

```
{ test: /\.js\.dust\.haml/, loader: 'dust-loader!val-loader!haml-haml' }
```

From webpack's documentation:

> val: Executes code as module and consider exports as JavaScript code

and per the loader documentation itself:

> This loader is also useful if you want to provide data for another loader